# Add a class to certain actions in SwaggerUI

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an Asp.Net Core API project that is using Swagger / SwaggerUI.

Is there a way to add a CSS class to certain actions in SwaggerUI so that I can visually differentiate them using a custom css file that I've already injected into SwaggerUI?
In particular, I would like a visual indication of which authorization scheme each action uses (some use Azure AD, others a custom, signed Jwt).

I'm using an IOperationFilter to apply the correct authorization scheme to each action but can't see anything in there that I could set that might cause SwaggerUI to add a class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any method can add a css file to specified action in SwaggerUI, But from your question, I think you just want to add some marks on SwaggerUI to distinguish different endpoints, So you can try this method:

**Add some Configurations in program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

**Select Options**

[image]

**Then you can add a summary on specified action**

```
        /// <summary>
        ///  Azure AD
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Test(OuterModel testmodel)
        {
            return Ok(testmodel);
        }
```

**Now, The summary will show in endpoint**

[image]

**I Hope this solution can help you.**